# Send an alert when the maximum number of characters is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like that when an user tries to past in my textbox and his text is bigger then the maximum amount of counter, an alert shows up.

I have this code that does all right apart from the alert.

```
$("#faketxt").bind("paste", function(e){
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    var charsLeft = 19200 - $(this).text().length;
    if(pastedData.length > charsLeft){
        $(this).text( $(this).text() + pastedData.substring(0, charsLeft));
        return false;
                alert("Hai raggiunto il limite di caratteri!");
    }
    return true;
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

When you `return false;` the method is ended and no more code runs including your `alert();` call. Move the `alert();` call to before the `return false;`.